# How to take data that is in "long format" into "wide" format but keep some categorical columns the same

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data set that's in "long format" which I have listed below.

[image]

My goal is convert this data into a shorter format.
I have this code but I keep getting NA's in the Sum column.

```
data %>% 
group_by(Month, Year, Status) %>% 
  summarise(Sum = sum(Count))
```

[image]

data

```
data <- structure(list(Month = c("Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", 
"Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", 
"Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", 
"Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", 
"Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", 
"Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", 
"Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", 
"Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", "Sep", 
"Sep", "Sep", "Sep"), Year = c(2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L), Status = c("Active", "Inactive", 
"Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", 
"Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", 
"Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", 
"Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", 
"Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", 
"Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", 
"Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", 
"Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", 
"Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", 
"Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", 
"Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive", 
"Active", "Inactive", "Active", "Inactive"), Count = c(1L, 6L, 
3L, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 208L, 327L, 12L, 10L, 192L, 
1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 223L, 3L, 278L, 454L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 8L, 31L, 
2L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 
3L, 175L, 259L, 18L, 19L, NA, NA, 179L, 49L, 1L, 1L, 191L, 2L, 
190L, 313L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, NA, NA, 8L, 3L, 11L, 1L, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-72L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have the code correct. You just need to account for the NAs with `na.rm = TRUE`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Month, Year, Status) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Sum = sum(Count, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
# Groups:   Month, Year [2]
  Month  Year Status     Sum
  <chr> <int> <chr>    <int>
1 Oct    2021 Active     977
2 Oct    2021 Inactive   843
3 Sep    2021 Active     797
4 Sep    2021 Inactive   675
```

Then, if you want to get the percentage for each Status by Month and Year, then you can `mutate` a new column.

```
data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Month, Year, Status) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Sum = sum(Count, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  # Need to ungroup the Status column.
  dplyr::ungroup(Status) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(percent = (Sum / sum(Sum)) * 100)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
# Groups:   Month, Year [2]
  Month  Year Status     Sum  percent
  <chr> <int> <chr>    <int> <dbl>
1 Oct    2021 Active     977  53.7
2 Oct    2021 Inactive   843  46.3
3 Sep    2021 Active     797  54.1
4 Sep    2021 Inactive   675  45.9
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is there an easy to make a new column that will show the me the percentage of each Month, Year, Status? For example OCT 2021 Active will be 54% and the Inactive will be 46%.

Comment: @RL_Pug I've updated my answer to include a percent column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just needed the na.rm = TRUE part in the Sum

```
out <- data %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Month, Year, Status) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Sum = sum(Count, na.rm = TRUE))

out
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Month, Year [2]
  Month  Year Status     Sum
  <chr> <int> <chr>    <int>
1 Oct    2021 Active     977
2 Oct    2021 Inactive   843
3 Sep    2021 Active     797
4 Sep    2021 Inactive   675
```